# How to read pom version in cloudbuild

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, gitops, cloudbuild.yaml

I have cloudbuild.yaml file which is deploying java application. Right now i am passing commit id as my docker image tag. But i want to pass pom version in my docker build. There is a way to read pom file in jenkins with readMavenPom().getArtifactId() function. Is there something similar in cloudbuild too?My build and push steps looks similar to the below cloudbuild.yaml

```
                   - id: "docker build"  
                     name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
                     args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/PID/test:$SHORT_SHA', '.']
                     name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
                     args: ['push', 'gcr.io/PID/TEST:$SHORT_SHA']
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: yes still not resolved

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to currently pass the content of the pom file in cloudbbuild as it's done with jenkins. Maybe you should create a feature request to gcp through this link https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers